# Dynamic select with ancestry gem and chosen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, jquery-chosen, ancestry

I am looking for dynamic select by using chosen and ancestry gem and I hope someone done this before.

I have around 2000 (categories, subcategories and keywords) all are in STI and have a tree structure. In my form  I'm using three select input for categories | subcategories | keywords, but I  get huge list of subcategories and even bigger list of keywords. I want to hide all subcategories, that are not children of preselected categories; same with keywords.

Hopefully this is has a sense, what I am trying to do. I would greatly appreciate any ideas.

Here what I have so far, and all of this code is working great.

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, :join_table => "companies_categories"
has_and_belongs_to_many :subcategories, :join_table => "companies_subcategories"
has_and_belongs_to_many :keywords, :join_table => "companies_keywords"
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
has_ancestry  :cache_depth => true, :depth_cache_column => :ancestry_depth

has_many :subcategories, :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key => :subcategory_id
has_many :keywords, :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key => :keyword_id

belongs_to :category

has_and_belongs_to_many :companies, :join_table => "companies_categories"
has_and_belongs_to_many :companies, :join_table => "companies_subcategories", :association_foreign_key => "subcategory_id"
has_and_belongs_to_many :companies, :join_table => "companies_keywords", :association_foreign_key => "keyword_id"

end
```

Here is javascript

```
jQuery(function($){
$(".chosen-input").chosen();
$(".schosen-input").chosen();
$(".kchosen-input").chosen();
});
```

Here is my form

```
form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" }  do |f|
f.inputs "New Company" do
  f.input :name,  :required => true
end

f.inputs "Categories" do

  f.input :categories,
          :input_html => { :class => "chosen-input", :multiple => true, :style => "width: 700px;"},
          :collection => Category.where(:ancestry_depth => '2')


  f.input :subcategories,
          :input_html => { :class => "schosen-input", :multiple => true, :style => "width: 700px;"},
          :collection => Category.where(:ancestry_depth => '3')


  f.input :keywords,
          :input_html => { :class => "schosen-input", :multiple => true, :style => "width: 700px;"},
          :collection => Category.where(:ancestry_depth => [4, 5, 6])

end
```

Comment: I am also interested... maybe this could help you? http://staal.io/blog/2013/02/26/mastering-activeadmin/

Answer (score 1):

I use select2 but I think it's possible with chosen, too. So, you have to use ajax request.
Define an action on server side what get a category id (the id of the chosen category), and returns the collection of the categories (in json format) that children of the chosen category id. Then on client side (with jquery or javasciprt) you have to populate the select input with the json object.

JQuery event you can use: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Populate the select input: [jQuery-- Populate select from json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442422/jquery-populate-select-from-json)

And in ActiveAdmin you have to determine the select input based on the DOM.