# jQuery-- Populate select from json

Tags: jquery

I have a map in my java sevlet and converting it to a json format that works right.

When I do this function below it creates a drop down, but it puts every character as an option??
This is what I got:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var temp= '${temp}';
    //alert(options);
    var $select = $('#down');                        
    $select.find('option').remove();                          
    $.each(temp, function(key, value) {              
        $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($select);     
    });
});
```

map content in JSON format

```
{"1" : "string","2" : "string"}
```

Comment: Are you sure the temp variable is correct?

Comment: You are not reading a json object but a string so $.each is getting each letter of a string. Try to console.log(temp); so u can have an idea of object you are dealling with

Comment: You may need to also do a `JSON.parse` of your temp variable to convert it from a string to an actual js object.

Comment: @ColinDeClue ..Yep...that did it!

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```js
$.each(temp, function(key, value) {
  $select.append(`<option value="${key}">${value}</option>`);
});
```

JSON structure would be appreciated. At first you can experiment with `find('element')` - it depends on JSON.

Comment: it should be $.each(temp,function(key, value)

Comment: `temp` is not a jQuery object... it doesn't have .each or .find.

Comment: This solution has poor performance, it modifies the DOM in each iteration, better build the option in a string and then append it to the select outside the loop.

Comment: @Esteban Performance is fine unless you have several thousand fields.

Answer (score 52):

Only change the DOM once...

```
var listitems = '';
$.each(temp, function(key, value){
    listitems += '<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>';
});
$select.append(listitems);
```

Comment: You must do ```var listitems = '';``` or else you get an undefined on concat

Answer (score 13):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chauhangs/vTaZq/)

```
var $select = $('#down'); 
$select.find('option').remove();  
$.each(temp,function(key, value) 
{
    $select.append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>');
});
```

Comment: That'd work the same as what he already has. There's something wrong with his `temp` variable, not with how he's generating the options.

Comment: If the JSON Map he posted is correct then the code should run fine

Comment: print your temp console.log(temp); and see if it is a valid JSON or not

Comment: $select.find('optgroup').remove(); also removes any optgroup's you might have. I like this solution because it replaces the entire select options/optgroups which is what I needed.

Answer (score 7):

A solution is to create your own jquery plugin that take the json map and populate the select with it.

```
(function($) {     
     $.fn.fillValues = function(options) {
         var settings = $.extend({
             datas : null, 
             complete : null,
         }, options);

         this.each( function(){
            var datas = settings.datas;
            if(datas !=null) {
                $(this).empty();
                for(var key in datas){
                    $(this).append('<option value="'+key+'"+>'+datas[key]+'</option>');
                }
            }
            if($.isFunction(settings.complete)){
                settings.complete.call(this);
            }
        });

    }

}(jQuery));
```

You can call it by doing this :

```
$("#select").fillValues({datas:your_map,});
```

The advantages is that anywhere you will face the same problem you just call

```
 $("....").fillValues({datas:your_map,});
```

Et voila !

You can add functions in your plugin as you like

Answer (score 3):

```
$(JSON.parse(response)).map(function () {
    return $('<option>').val(this.value).text(this.label);
}).appendTo('#selectorId');
```

Comment: FYI, $.parseJSON is now deprecated. The native JSON.parse() is preferred.

Answer (score 2):

I just used the javascript console in Chrome to do this. I replaced some of your stuff with placeholders.

```js
var temp= ['one', 'two', 'three']; //'${temp}';
//alert(options);
var $select = $('<select>'); //$('#down');                        
$select.find('option').remove();                          
$.each(temp, function(key, value) {              
    $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($select);
});
console.log($select.html());
```

Output:

> <option value="0">one</option><option value="1">two</option><option value="2">three</option>

However it looks like your json is probably actually a string because the following will end up doing what you describe.  So make your JSON actual JSON not a string.

```js
var temp= "['one', 'two', 'three']"; //'${temp}';
//alert(options);
var $select = $('<select>'); //$('#down');                        
$select.find('option').remove();                          
$.each(temp, function(key, value) {              
    $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($select);
});
console.log($select.html());
```

Answer (score 1):

That work fine in Ajax call back to update select from JSON object

```
function UpdateList() {
    var lsUrl = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")';

    $.get(lsUrl, function (opdata) {

        $.each(opdata, function (key, value) {
            $('#myselect').append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>');
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe this can help you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var temp = {someKey:"temp value", otherKey:"other value", fooKey:"some value"};
    for (var key in temp) {
        alert('<option value=' + key + '>' + temp[key] + '</option>');
    }
});
```