# Is there a standard JQuery tool for populating a droplist with JSON data?

Tags: jquery, json, datatables, html-select

I'm looking for something like the dataTables plugin for droplists.  I know from looking all morning for a simple example, that there are a million ways to do this, but I haven't found anything like a canonical method.  Given JSON containing a list of data, what's the simplest way, in JQuery, to fill a droplist with it?

Let's just assume for the moment that this json data comes from a database query accessed through a Spring MVC controller method.  But really, any JSON list served by an URL should work.

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave an example of the JSON you want converted into "droplists" ( which I assume you mean select/option? )

Comment: Maybe this link can give you some ideas to solve the problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442422/jquery-populate-select-from-json

Comment: by droplist I do, indeed mean select/option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it.  First of all, the Json was about as basic as you can imagine:

```
{"status":"OK",
 "statusDescription":"2 rows returned",
 "payload":{
   "transcribers":[
        {"userId":2,"userName":"jfrost"},
        {"userId":1,"userName":"sjones"}
   ]
  }
}
```

The solution was none too difficult once I understood the problem, a headscratcher until then.

```
function loadTranscriberDropdown() 
{
    var transcriberAPI = "oam/transcribers/";
    var count = 0;
    console.log('in loadTranscriberDropdown()');    

    $('#userlist').empty().append('<option value="0">...</option>');
    $.getJSON(transcriberAPI) 
        .done(function( data ) {
            $.each(data.payload.transcribers, function( ID, value ) {
                $('#userlist').append('<option value=' + value.userId + '>' + value.userName + '</option>');
                count = count + 1;
                console.log("loaded " + value.userName);
            });
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log( "  error loading transcribers. " );
        })
        .always(function() {
            console.log( count + " transcribers loaded.");
        });

}
```

What was confusing me was why the inline function in the $.each line had to be of the form `function ( key, value )`.  It isn't obvious that each row of the supplied JSON is part of a key-value pair.  There seems to be some sort of implied key for each member of the list, its order in the list, first row's key is 1, 2nd is 2, etc.  Thus all the data is in the value element.

Anyway, I hope this will prove useful to the next person who has to solve this "simple" problem.

Comment: Good work. You should accept your own answer - I am sure it will help other people in the future.