# how to get json data in jquery for dinamic combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, combobox

[I have json data in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbMwU.png) 
Which is obtained from the Propinsi id but I do not understand how to use json data into my combobox, my script in here... please tell me how to correct this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#propinsi').on('change',function(){
        var prop_kode = $('#propinsi').val();
        console.log(prop_kode);
        if (prop_kode == "") {
            $('#kabupaten').prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else {
            $('#kabupaten').prop('disabled', false);
            $.ajax({
                url:"<?=$url; ?>/show_kabupaten",
                type:"POST",
                data: {'prop_kode' : prop_kode},
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(data){
                    $('#kabupaten').html(data);
                       // $.each(json, function(i, value) {
                            $('#kabupaten').append($('<option>').text('Pilih Kabupaten').attr('value', 'value'));
                            $.each( kabupaten, function( kab_nama, kab_kode ) {
                            alert( kabupaten.kab_nama);
                        });
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('error .......');
                }
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What's happening now? What errors are in the console if you hit F12?

Comment: If you want to create select options using json then check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442422/jquery-populate-select-from-json).

Comment: in console is no error, and it show that 
{"kabupaten":[{"kab_id":"8","prop_kode":"12","kab_kode":"1201","kab_nama":"KABUPATEN NIAS","kab_status":"1","kab_created_by":"1","kab_created_date":"1496631492"},{"kab_id":"9","prop_kode":"12","kab_kode":"1202","kab_nama":"KABUPATEN MANDAILING NATAL","kab_status":"1","kab_created_by":"1","kab_created_date":"1496631518"}]}

Comment: Replace `dataType: 'html'` with `dataType: 'json'` and access the json object with `data.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Something like this?**

```js
$('#propinsi').on('change', function() {
  var prop_kode = $('#propinsi').val();

  if (prop_kode == "") {
    $('#kabupaten').prop('disabled', true);
    return;
  }

  $('#kabupaten').prop('disabled', false);

  // This is just because I don't know where to find your json data
  var data = JSON.parse('{"kabupaten":[{"kab_id":"8","prop_kode":"12","kab_kode":"120‌​1","kab_nama":"KABUP‌​ATEN NIAS","kab_status":"1","kab_created_by":"1","kab_created_dat‌​e":"1496631492"},{"k‌​ab_id":"9","prop_kod‌​e":"12","kab_kode":"‌​1202","kab_nama":"KA‌​BUPATEN MANDAILING NATAL","kab_status":"1","kab_created_by":"1","kab_created_da‌​te":"1496631518"}]}');

  $("#kabupaten").html("");

  $.each(data.kabupaten, function(i, kab) {
    var id = kab.kab_id;
    var name = kab.kab_nama;
    $("#kabupaten").append('<option value="' + id + '">' + name + '</option>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="propinsi">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
    
<br>

<select id="kabupaten"></select>
```

To implement it into your JS, the code below may help.

```
// Add this code just below the line $('#kabupaten').prop('disabled', false);
$.ajax({
    url: "<?=$url; ?>/show_kabupaten",
    type: "POST",
    data: {'prop_kode': prop_kode},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        $("#kabupaten").html("");

        $.each(data.kabupaten, function(i, kab) {
            var id = kab.kab_id;
            var name = kab.kab_nama;
            $("#kabupaten").append('<option value="'+id+'">'+name+'</option>');
        });
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('error .......');
    }
});
```

Comment: Does json parse it filled the url of the data it gets? for example url:"<?=$url; ?>/show_kabupaten" ??

Comment: if you use `dataType: 'json'` as an option in your `$.ajax({})` request, then `JSON.parse(...)` is not needed.

Comment: Oh, your `<?=$url; ?>` is PHP?

Comment: yes, <?=$url; ?> is PHP
in my code is this  $.ajax({
url:"<?=$url; ?>/show_kabupaten",
   type:"POST",
   data: {'prop_kode' : prop_kode},
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data){ ... 
so, What should I do?

Comment: My pleasure :) Good luck