# bootstrap-select doesn't populate from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am trying to populate a `bootstrap-select` control using the following AJAX call:

```
    function loadCategories() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../handlers/getcategorylist.ashx',
            data: null,
            method: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                $('#ddlCategories').html(JSON.stringify(data));
                $('#ddlCategories').selectpicker('refresh');
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

The HTML for the `bootstrap-select` is as follows:

```
                        <div class="row mb-2">
                            <div class="col-lg-10 offset-lg-1">
                                <select id="ddlCategories" name="ddlCategories" data-width="25%" class="form-control selectpicker">
                                    <option value="select">Select From The List</option>
                                 </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

The AJAX call executes and is successful.  Using `JSON.stringify()` I get the following data back (shown in an alert):

[image: alert window showing data returned from AJAX call]

For whatever reason, the `bootstrap-select` doesn't populate.  It displays empty.  What am I missing here?

Comment: could you show the html and version of bootstrap-select

Comment: Amended post to include HTML of bootstrap-select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi it seems like you're setting the inner HTML of your select element to a array of objects. You probably have to [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) through all the objects inside of your response array and append them to the select element (like described in the following [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16442523/880057). If you'd also like to remove existing content from the select element consider setting the html to blank.

So something along the lines of:

```
data.forEach(entry => {
    $('#ddlCategories').append(`<option value=${entry['ID']}> ${entry['Name']} </option>`);
});
```

Comment: How would that work in the context of my code?

Comment: @TC_Guy changed my original comment to include a code example.